# Unit tests in Python with pytest

Tags: python, pytest

Currently my project's directory is organized as the following structure:

```
.
+-- module1
+-- module2
...
+-- moduleN
+-- test
    +-- test_module1_item1.py
    ...
    +-- test_moduleN_itemM.py
```

But when I execute `py.test` in my upper level directory, it throws an error like:

> ImportError: No module named 'module1'

How the imports in the test files should be declared? Or how my project structure should be defined in order to the tests be separated from the rest of the code?

Comment: are all the ``__init__.py`` present? Seems like you are not finding your module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect `__init__.py` is missing from `./test`

```
» ls *
module1:
__init__.py

test:
test_module1_item1.py
```

Let's try testing

```
» py.test
... 
ERROR collecting test/test_module1_item1.py     
test/test_module1_item1.py:8: in <module>
    import module1
E   ImportError: No module named module1
```

This looks like your error.

```
» touch test/__init__.py
» py.test

test/test_module1_item1.py:10: in <module>
    assert 1 == 2
E   assert 1 == 2
```

This looks like your solution. I suspect py.test is doing something with the $pythonpath based on whether `./test` is a module or not.